# Custom Mean Function Construction for GPFlow Regression

Tags: python, tensorflow, regression, gpflow

I am trying to pass a custom mean function into GPflow 2.0.  I have some (x,y,z) data with several observations for each x,y point.  I wanted to pass the average z value for each (x,y) pair as the mean function.  My code for the custom mean function is below where `train_xy` are the (x,y,z) tuples in my training data (x and y are inputs, and z is the output).

Below is my code setting up the mean function and passing it into a simple GPR model.

---

```
class CustomMean(gpflow.mean_functions.MeanFunction):
    """
    means = mean(grouped by unique tuples of input1 & input2)
    """

    def __init__(self, X):
        # MeanFunction.__init__(self)
        self.X = Parameter(X)

    def __call__(self, X):
        mean_arr = []
        X = np.unique(X, axis=0)
        for i in range(len(X)):
            y_list = train_xy[(train_xy['input1'] == X[i, 0]) & (train_xy['input2'] == X[i, 1])]['output']
            mean_arr.append(y_list.mean())
        mean_arr = np.asarray(mean_arr, dtype=np.float64)
        mean_arr[np.isnan(mean_arr)] = 0
        means = tf.convert_to_tensor(mean_arr)
        return means
    
    
k = gpflow.kernels.Linear()
mean_func = CustomMean(X_train.values.astype('float64'))
m = gpflow.models.GPR(data=(X_train, y_train), kernel=k, mean_function=mean_func)

pred_mean, pred_var = m.predict_f(X_test.values.astype('float64'))
```

---

I ran into problems when I called the `predict_f` function:

---

```
InvalidArgumentError                      Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-140-c7b24d06c38e> in <module>()
----> 1 pred_mean, pred_var = m.predict_f(X_test.values.astype('float64'))

~/anaconda3/envs/tensorflow_p36/lib/python3.6/site-packages/gpflow/models/gpr.py in predict_f(self, Xnew, full_cov, full_output_cov)
    103             kmn, kmm + s, knn, err, full_cov=full_cov, white=False
    104         )  # [N, P], [N, P] or [P, N, N]
--> 105         f_mean = f_mean_zero + self.mean_function(Xnew)
    106         return f_mean, f_var

...

InvalidArgumentError: Incompatible shapes: [1250,2596] vs. [1104] [Op:AddV2]
```

---

And it looks like the error is tied to something called `f_mean = f_mean_zero + self.mean_function(Xnew)`.  When I look at the shape of this, the dimensions are very large.  I have 2596 unique (x,y) pairs in my training data (out of 3750 total rows) and 1104 unique (x,y) pairs in test (out of 1250 total rows).  `f_mean_zero` is (1250, 2596), whereas `self.mean_function(Xnew)` returns a one-dimensional tensor of means (as expected). I don't understand the dimension of `f_mean_zero`, particularly since (x,y) pairs in my test data are in my training data.
It seems like a similar issue to [this ticket](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58967225/building-custom-mean-functions-in-gpflow2-0) but there is no solution. Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

I have a couple of pointers that should help you solve your issue:

1. It is important to remember that GPflow uses TensorFlow for most of its computations. The inputs and outputs of many operations (like the `__call__` of a mean function) are assumed to be `tf.Tensor`s and not `np.ndarray`s as is the case in your snippet. Operations like `len()`, `np.unique`, etc. are not supported by `tf.Tensor`s and will have to be correctly translated to TensorFlow ops. That being said, the task you want to achieve is not straightforward to implement with Tensor logic in TensorFlow. I believe you will have to use operations like [tf.where](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/where).
2. The stack trace you provided shows mismatching shapes. The output of the mean function's call should have the same leading dimensions as the input (`X` in your case). Example: if `X` has shape `[N, D]`, the output of the call should have shape `[N, 1]`.
3. It is unclear to me why you are storing `X` as a parameter in the init of your mean function. Can you elaborate on that?

Hope this helps you on your way.

Answer (score 0):

Have you considered subtracting the mean out of your data and modeling it with a zero mean GPR, then adding the mean back afterwards?  That would achieve the same effect without having to create the custom class.